# PhoneGap CLI "cordova build ios" failed

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-cli

i have created a new hello world project using the following command,

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

the project is created successfully, then i add the ios platform by

```
cordova platform add ios
```

and to verify i have it added correctly, i type

```
cordova platform list
```

the iOS platform is shown in the list. so at this point, according to the PhoneGap tutorial, i can use the command

```
cordova build ios
```

to build the iOS version of the project. however, i encounter the following error:

```
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "ios"
Preparing ios project
Compiling app on platform "ios" via command "/Users/Aldour/PhoneGap/hello/platforms/ios/cordova/build" 

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                      ^
Error: An error occurred while building the ios project.
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/compile.js:65:22)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:948:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

the results that i have googled are mostly concerning the android version, talking about the invalid environment path setting. i dont know if it is related since i can create and build a PhoneGap project targeting the android platform without problem.

here is my $PATH:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin/node:/usr/local/bin/npm:/Developer/SDKs/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Developer/SDKs/android-sdk-macosx/tools
```

EDIT:
problem solved by re-installing xcode from app store

Comment: Whenever I've seen this error with Cordova, it's usually because the version of Cordova I had was not compatible with the version of the native SDK being used.  I can't speak for iOS, but I've definitely seen this error before with both Android and BlackBerry10. Certain Cordova builds introduced support for platform APIs.  If you are using a newer version of one without the other, then it may cause compile errors like the above.

Comment: @AdamStanley thanks for the response. so how to revert to a older version of cordova if i want to? i installed it with "sudo npm install -g cordova"

Comment: I have always removed the existing node (npm uninstall -g cordova), and then do a fresh install. To install a specific version of an NPM module, you can do this "npm install <name>@<version>".  More: https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in Android platform, and it was solved with the commands:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
```

in Node.Js console. try it in ios.

If you get an error with 'cordova platform add android', you may need to manually remove any android folders in your project folder hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

This resolved my issue:

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
cordova build ios
```

Answer (score 4):

If you run the build with --verbose, you will probably see some permission issues.  By default, XCode creates a folder of the build in ~/Developer, if you haven't changed it.  There probably is a permissions issue when creating that folder.  Just execute the following command:  sudo cordova bulid ios
That should fix your issue.